# What is the logic behind this prolog code?

Tags: prolog

i have short Prolog code that finds last element of given list.

```
last_of([_|Tail], X) :- last_of(Tail, X), !.
last_of([X], X).
```

but i have a question about logic of this program. why we use `last_of([X], X).`, i couldn't understand this. can you explain?

Comment: In any language, a recursive implementation requires a termination case which will decide to provide a result rather than make the recursive call.

Comment: @mbratch: But, in this case, the termination case is encoded in the recursive rule which is quite unusual for a procedural mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several comments to your program:

1st, the name is a misnomer. The first argument is a list, the second is the last element. But your name suggests otherwise. A better name would be `list_last/2` or simply `last/2`.

2nd, the cut is misplaced.  In fact, by simply exchanging the rules and removing the cut, you get the significantly more efficient, and also more declarative:

```
last([X]   , X).
last([_|Xs], X) :- last(Xs,X).
```

Now to your question. When starting programming in Prolog, the best is to imagine **ground** queries first. So let's make several examples where the relation should succeed.

```
?- last([a],a).
```

For this to be true, a fact `last([a],a).` would be sufficient. We can *generalize* the fact then to `last([X],X).`. After that, we might consider a list with two elements for which the fact `last([_,X],X).` would cover all lists of length 2. Etc.

```
last([X],X).
last([_,X],X).
last([_,_,X],X).
...
```

Now, let's generalize this pattern! Lets reduce a case of a longer list to a shorter list.  To do this, I *assume* that I know already the last element of `Xs`:

```
????   :-
   last(Xs, X).
```

What can we conclude when we already know that `X` is the last element of `Xs`?  We can conclude that a list which is longer by one element will have the very same `X` as the last element, too! Thus:

```
last([_|Xs], X) :-
   list(Xs, X).
```

So with this rule, we can make the list longer and longer. But only if there is a case where we can start from! For this reason you need `list([X],X).` It is best to add this fact *first*, because you will find answers for the goal `list(Xs, a)`, too.

Please note the particular way how I looked at the `:-`. I read it as an right-to-left arrow implying something new: If the goals on the right are true, then also the goals on the left will be true.

Frequently, people try to understand Prolog rules in exactly the way how Prolog executes them. And that is not right-to-left as I did, but left-to-right. However, this reading is very unintuitive for humans, since Prolog uses a quite unusual way to execute: On the one hand it uses unification which is far more complex than pattern matching and then backtracking. Both notions are not present in traditional programming languages, thereby confusing you more than they help.

Comment: actually, can you explain why ?- last([a],a). gives true.

last_of([_|Tail], X) :- last_of(Tail, X), !.


last_of([X], X).
i dont understand second row.

Comment: why when we query last([a],a). then prolog gives true?

Comment: Because, as stated in your axioms, `last_of([X], X)` is true for every `X`.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is inherently recursive when evaluating. When it reaches `last_of(Tail, X)`
It checks last_of() again, with Tail as the new first argument.

Obviously this needs some way to stop, so you are given the assertion that X is always the last element in a list containing only X.